# Increment and Decrement function bugs in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, increment, decrement

I started learning Objective-C a few weeks ago. I have no problem until I created "Add to Cart" function. In the "Add to Cart" function I have to 2 buttons, a plus button and a minus button. The Plus button is for increasing the value by 1, minus button is for decreasing the value by 1. It looks like this:

[image: Interface]

The problem is the plus button stops increasing the value at 9. So after the value is 9, if I click the plus button, the value changes to 1. If I click the plus button again, it turns to 11. If I click again, it turns to 1. If I click again, plus button does not increase the value anymore. Logs show the value correctly but not with the UI. Here are the logs:

[image: Logs]

This is my code:

```
#import "ThirdViewController.h"

@interface ThirdViewController ()

@end

@implementation ThirdViewController

-(void)viewWillAppear{
    self.i = 0;
}

- (IBAction)plusBtn:(UIButton *)sender {
    self.i++;
    [_txtNumber setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",self.i]];
    NSLog(@"%d",self.i);
}

- (IBAction)minusBtn:(UIButton *)sender {
    --self.i;
    [_txtNumber setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",self.i]];
    NSLog(@"Minus");
}

- (IBAction)addToCartBtn:(UIButton *)sender {
    NSLog(@"Add");
}
@end
```

Comment: Sounds like your label isn't wide enough to show the whole string value.

Comment: OOO MY GOSH, thank you very much. I don't know that could be a problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the label wider. Obviously, the problem is in UI